# How should I display ~1600 sparklines in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, optimization, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How should I display ~1600 sparklines in Google Sheets?  I'm trying to build a spreadsheet to screen ~400 stocks.  I would like to use something similar to sparklines to provide quick trends in 5-yr prices, 6-mo prices, trailing 5-yr revenue, and 3-yr projected revenue.  So, this would mean I would like to display, at most, ~1600 sparklines. The spreadsheet only needs to be updated once a week. Currently, I am testing a function (shown below) to generate the sparklines for each cell corresponding the stock ticker.  It works decently for one column of sparklines, but, when I try to do two or more columns of sparklines (~800 sparklines), the script (also show below) exceeds maximum execution time.  [The spreadsheet can be seen here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CC3Kw60oFZoRAhAilzKyvj_u9tDjmDTS5zyt_vniVAM/edit?usp=sharing)

Code snippet for sparklines:

```
// Global variables
var firstRow = 4;
var lastRow = 400;

var tickerColumn = "E";

function getPriceChartFromGoogle( pColumn, pDays) {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange( pColumn + firstRow + ':' + pColumn + lastRow );
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setFormula( '= SPARKLINE( GoogleFinance( ' + tickerColumn + firstRow + ', "price", TODAY()-' + pDays + ', TODAY() ) )' );
}
```

Full script:

```
// Global variables
var sheetName = "Stocks Screener";
var headerRow = 3;
var firstRow = 4;
var lastRow = 400;

var firstColumn = 'A';
var tickerColumn = "E";
var priceColumn = 'F';
var sixMonthsPriceChartColumn = 'G';
var fiveYearPriceChartColumn = 'H';
var bookValueColumn = 'I';
var priceToBookColumn = 'J';
var earningPerShareColumn = 'K';
var priceToEarningsRatioColumn = 'L';
var debtToEquityRatioColumn = 'M';
var operatingCashFlowColumn = 'N';
var leveredFreeCashFlowColumn = 'O';
var sectorColumn = 'P';
var lastColumn = 'Z';

updateData();

function updateData() {
  getSector();
  getPriceFromGoogle();
  getSixMonthPriceChartFromGoogle();
  getFiveYearPriceChartFromGoogle();
  getBookValuePerShareFromYahoo();
  getEarningPerShareFromGoogle();
  getPriceToEarningsRatioFromGoogle();
  getDebtToEquityRatioFromYahoo();
  getOperatingCashFlowFromYahoo();
  getLeveredFreeCashFlowFromYahoo();

  setHeaderFormat();
}

function setHeaderFormat() {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange( firstColumn + headerRow + ':' + lastColumn + headerRow );
  cellRange.setWrap(true);
}

function getPriceFromGoogle() {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange( priceColumn + headerRow );
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setValue("CURRENT PRICE (from Google)");

  cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange( priceColumn + firstRow + ':' + priceColumn + lastRow );
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setFormula( '= GOOGLEFINANCE( ' + tickerColumn + firstRow + ' )' );
  cellRange.setValues( cellRange.getValues() );
}

function getPriceChartFromGoogle( pColumn, pDays) {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange( pColumn + firstRow + ':' + pColumn + lastRow );
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setFormula( '= SPARKLINE( GoogleFinance( ' + tickerColumn + firstRow + ', "price", TODAY()-' + pDays + ', TODAY() ) )' );
}

function getSixMonthPriceChartFromGoogle() {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange( sixMonthsPriceChartColumn + headerRow );
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setValue("6 MO PRICE CHART (from Google)");

  getPriceChartFromGoogle( sixMonthsPriceChartColumn,183 );
}

function getFiveYearPriceChartFromGoogle() {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange( fiveYearPriceChartColumn + headerRow );
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setValue("5 YR PRICE CHART (from Google)");

  getPriceChartFromGoogle( fiveYearPriceChartColumn,1780 );
}

function getBookValuePerShareFromYahoo() {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange( bookValueColumn + firstRow + ':' + bookValueColumn + lastRow );
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setFormula( '= ( INDEX( IMPORTHTML( "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & $' + tickerColumn + firstRow + '& "/key-statistics?p=" & $' + tickerColumn + firstRow + ',"table",8 ),6,2 ) )' );
  cellRange.setValues( cellRange.getValues() );
}

function getEarningPerShareFromGoogle() {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange( earningPerShareColumn + firstRow + ':' + earningPerShareColumn + lastRow );
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setFormula( '= GOOGLEFINANCE( ' + tickerColumn + firstRow + ', "eps" )' );
  cellRange.setValues( cellRange.getValues() );
}

function getPriceToEarningsRatioFromGoogle() {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange( priceToEarningsRatioColumn + firstRow + ':' + priceToEarningsRatioColumn + lastRow );
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setFormula( '= GOOGLEFINANCE( ' + tickerColumn + firstRow + ', "pe" )' );
  cellRange.setValues( cellRange.getValues() );
}

function getDebtToEquityRatioFromYahoo() {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(debtToEquityRatioColumn + firstRow + ':' + debtToEquityRatioColumn + lastRow);
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setFormula( '= INDEX( IMPORTHTML( "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & $' + tickerColumn + firstRow + ' & "/key-statistics?p=" & $' + tickerColumn + firstRow + ',"table",8 ),4,2 )' );
  cellRange.setValues( cellRange.getValues() );
}

function getOperatingCashFlowFromYahoo() {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(operatingCashFlowColumn + firstRow + ':' + operatingCashFlowColumn + lastRow);
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setFormula( '= INDEX( IMPORTHTML( "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & $' + tickerColumn + firstRow + '& "/key-statistics?p=" & $' + tickerColumn + firstRow + ',"table",9 ),1,2 )' );
  cellRange.setValues( cellRange.getValues() );
}

function getLeveredFreeCashFlowFromYahoo() {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange( leveredFreeCashFlowColumn + firstRow + ':' + leveredFreeCashFlowColumn + lastRow);
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setFormula( '= INDEX( IMPORTHTML( "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & $' + tickerColumn + firstRow + '& "/key-statistics?p=" & $' + tickerColumn + firstRow + ',"table",9 ),2,2 )' );
  cellRange.setValues( cellRange.getValues() );
}

function getSector() {
  var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange( sectorColumn + firstRow + ':' + sectorColumn + lastRow);
  cellRange.clear();
  cellRange.setFormula( '= index( importxml( "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/goto/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols="&' + tickerColumn + firstRow + '&"","//div[@class=\'sub-heading\']//span[@class=\'right\']"),1)' );
  cellRange.setValues( cellRange.getValues() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It' a bad idea to call a function from the global scope b/c every time that you call any function from a custom menu, a formula having a custom function, etc. that function will be executed.

While it might look to have a function for every kind of chart, from a spreadsheet performance perspective  it's not a good idea to have so many calls to the Spreadsheet Service b/c they are slow specially those methods that change it like `clear()`, `setValues()`, `setFormula()`.

To reduce to total execution time of your script you will have to change its logic in such way that the calls to Spreadsheet Service are reduced, i.e.

- instead of clearing one column at time, clear all of them in a single call
- instead of adding the formulas one column at a time, add all the formulas at once
- etc.